# Footer not showing with Paging 3

Tags: android, android-paging-3

I'm following the Codelab of Paging 3.

The paging is working fine, but trying to add a Footer does not seem to work.

My code is exactly like the Codelab one when it comes to `LoadStateAdapter` used

```
class ListLoadStateAdapter(
    private val retry: () -> Unit,
) : LoadStateAdapter<ListLoadStateAdapter.ListLoadStateViewHolder>() {

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ListLoadStateViewHolder, loadState: LoadState) {
        holder.bind(loadState)
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(
        parent: ViewGroup,
        loadState: LoadState,
    ) = ListLoadStateViewHolder.create(parent, retry)

    class ListLoadStateViewHolder(
        private val binding: ComponentPagedListFooterBinding,
        retry: () -> Unit,
    ) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {

        init {
            binding.buttonRetry.setOnClickListener { retry.invoke() }
        }

        fun bind(loadState: LoadState) {
            if (loadState is LoadState.Error) {
                binding.textViewPlaceholderError.text = loadState.error.localizedMessage
            }

            binding.progressBar.isVisible = loadState is LoadState.Loading
            binding.buttonRetry.isVisible = loadState is LoadState.Error
            binding.textViewPlaceholderError.isVisible = loadState is LoadState.Error

//            binding.root.isVisible = loadState is LoadState.Loading || loadState is LoadState.Error
        }

        companion object {
            fun create(parent: ViewGroup, retry: () -> Unit): ListLoadStateViewHolder {
                val binding = ComponentPagedListFooterBinding.inflate(
                    LayoutInflater.from(parent.context),
                    parent,
                    false,
                )

                return ListLoadStateViewHolder(binding, retry)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And this is how I add the footer

```kotlin
adapter = this@InvoiceListFragment.adapter.apply {
                withLoadStateFooter(ListLoadStateAdapter { retry() })

                addLoadStateListener {
                    viewModel.handlePagingState(it, this)
                }
            }
```

`handlePagingState` is just to follow the state and bind it to the Page state (Loading, Error, Empty, etc). Removing it changed nothing anyways.

The `ListLoadStateAdapter.onCreateViewHolder()` doesn't even get called, neither the constructor for `ListLoadStateViewHolder`.

What am I doing wrong? Is there something I missed? Or maybe a bug somewhere?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

My issue was that I was not setting the `ConcatAdapter` returned by `withLoadStateFooter`

```
recyclerView.adapter = adapter.withLoadStateFooter(
    footer = ListLoadStateAdapter { retry() }
)
```

Comment: where would you have to set it?

Comment: @mantc_sdr After these `yourAdapter.addLoadStateListener{} val contcatAdapter = yourAdapter.withLoadStateFooter(footer = YourLoadStateFooter{rourAdapter.retry()})`, you just do `rourRecyclerView.adapter = concatAdapter`

Comment: Set the returned `ConcatAdapter` to your `recyclerView` instead of the `PagingDataAdapter`.
`recyclerView.setAdapter(concatAdapter);`

Answer (score 4):

If anyone is still facing the same issue. You have to apply new adapter to the recycler view.

```
val adapterWithLoading = adapter.withLoadStateFooter(PagingLoadStateAdapter(adapter::retry))

binding.recycler.apply {
    layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
    adapter = adapterWithLoading
    addItemDecoration(ItemHorizontalDecorator())
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the save issue. My problem was that I initially try to load items from cache without internet and in that case footer didn't show up. When I load items from api than off internet - footer work normal.

Answer (score 0):

Improved from the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67228677/7735068

I have created an extension function for the same,

```
fun <T : Any, VH : RecyclerView.ViewHolder> PagingDataAdapter<T, VH>.loadFooter(): ConcatAdapter {

    Timber.e("Appending footer")
    return this.withLoadStateFooter(
        footer = FooterAdapter {
            this.retry()
        }
    )
}
```

So that we can call it directly during recycler view adapter initialization as,

```
rv.adapter = customPagingAdapter.loadFooter()
```

Rest of the FooterAdapter Impl. is same as codelabs.